# Determining if a set describes the degrees of vertices or not.

Tags: graph-theory

Full Question:
For each of the following lists, decide whether it is possible that the list represents the degrees of all the vertices of the graph. If so , draw such a graph, multigraph or psseudograph?

a) 2, 2, 2, 3

I am completely lost on how to do this, no idea where to start.

Comment: Arrange it in a non-increasing order and you get $(3,2,2,2)$ and now apply the Havel-Hakimi theorem to determine if it's a graphical sequence.

Comment: How many edges would such a graph have?

Comment: @TBolton: In your course, don't you already have the basic result that the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges?

Comment: Try drawing such a graph (hint: start with the vertex of largest degree).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Let $k = 2 + 2 + 2 +3$. Is $k$ even or odd?

Comment: I used the Havel-Hakimi theorem and ended up with -1 so that means that this sequence isnt graphical?

Comment: Yes. But just note that the sum of the degrees is odd.

Comment: So for all sets like the above if the sum of the degrees is odd then it isnt graphical?

Comment: @TBolton: If you're using a textbook, check the early sections (on graphs). Almost certainly, the fact that
$$\text{The sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges}$$
will be one of the first theorems.

Answer (score 0):

#### Without loops

Let's start by adding the stubs (the edge endpoints) according to the degree sequence:

[image]

Now let's try connecting them up:

[image]

It didn't work, because we have $9$ endpoints and we're trying to pair them up.  Edges have two endpoints.

Whether or not parallel edges are allowed doesn't matter: edges still have two endpoints.

#### With loops

If we allow loops, the answer depends on whether loops count 1 to the degree of a vertex, of if they count 2.  (Check your lecture notes as to what definition you are using.)

If loops count 2 to the degree, then it's the same problem as above: edges, including loops, have two endpoints.

If loops count 1 to the degree of a vertex, then we can finish off our above attempt:

[image]